# Why do you need to be on Linux to build website on Nodejs and react?

Tags: node.js

So i am using windows 7 but was advised to download a virtual machine with Ubuntu.iso to run linux? Why is that and why we cannot build website on Windows?

Comment: Node runs on windows, but windows 7 is really really old. Why are you on such an old operating system?

Comment: You haven't to use linux. You can run it on your OS as well.

Comment: TIL ten years is "really really old"

Comment: Advised by whom? How did that translate to "you need to be on Linux to build website on Nodejs and react"? This question lacks any meaningful context or premise.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, you can.

However, node's platforms features came later as an extra feature, and since most websites run on linux kernel based operating systems and servers, many npm package creators don't take the time to implement and to test their code on secondary platforms.

I guess you met someone maintaining a package, who does not have the time to debug windows issues.

Note that more and more developers don't have windows installed at all.